# Spring Mockito @MockBean fails while stepping through with debugger; works fine when not debugging

Tags: java, spring-boot, debugging, mockito, springmockito

I'm getting an error when I step through my test code with `@MockBean.thenReturn()` in a debugger (Intellij Java 17).   It works fine when it is executed outside the debugger though.

Here is a simplified version:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class MockitoBusted {

    @MockBean
    Target target;

    @Test
    void test() {
        var call = Mockito.when(target.x());
        // step over the below line and it fails.
        call.thenReturn(Collections.emptyList()); 
    }

    public static class Target {
        public List<String> x() {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    }
}
```

The failure occurs when stepping over the `call.thenReturn(...)` line.   The error message is:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
EmptyList cannot be returned by toString()
toString() should return String
***
If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on.
Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
1. This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests.
   Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency testing.
2. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies - 
   - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.
```

When using `Mockito.mock()` directly, this does not happen - everything works fine.

```java
        var target = Mockito.mock(Target.class);
        var call = Mockito.when(target.x());
        call.thenReturn(Collections.emptyList());
```

How is it possible that it fails when stepping over in the debugger, but works just fine when executed outside the debugger?

And is there a work-around for this?

Comment: The debugger causes a `.toString()` call on the `call` variable, recording a `.toString()` call. Hence trying to instrument `.toString()` to return the list. Just remove the `call` variable and have everything in one line.

Comment: @k5_ Wow, I didn't even think of this.  Thanks